# Python3 importlib.util.spec_from_file_location with relative path?

Tags: python

There are a lot of python questions about how to import [relative packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python) or by [explicit location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path) (linked to two popular examples).

In addition there is always the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

Having read this, I am still not quite sure what specs are, how they are related to modules, and why one would need to tokenize it.

So for someone who doesn't understand, could you please try to explain how one would do this (programmatically and what the means under the hood)

e.g.

if I have

```
proj-dir
--mod1
--|--__init__.py
--|--class1.py
--mod2
--|--__init__.py
--|--class2.py
```

how do I import mod2 into mod1?

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../mod2")
```

this technically works, but I fear that it may cause issues in the future if I try to pickle objects and use them elsewhere...

The [explicit location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path) suggested

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module.name", "/path/to/file.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
foo.MyClass()
```

so in this case I just do:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("mod2.class2", "../mod2/class2.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
foo.MyClass()
```

??

Comment: How do you plan on running the whole project? Do you want to run `mod1.class1` as a script i.e to do `python -m mod1.class1`?

Answer (score 10):

First of all, let me clarify the differences between a **Python module** & a **Python package** so that both of us are on the same page. ✌

---

###A module is **a single .py file (or files)** that are imported under one import and used. ✔
`import aModuleName

## Here 'aModuleName' is just a regular .py file.`

###Whereas, a package is a **collection of modules** in directories that give a package hierarchy. A package contains a distinct **`__init__.py`** file. ✔

```
 # Here 'aPackageName` is a folder with a `__init__.py` file
 # and 'aModuleName', which is just a regular .py file.
```

---

Therefore, the correct version of your **proj-dir** would be something like this, ⤵

```
 proj-dir
 ├── __init__.py
 ├── package1
 │   ├── __init__.py
 │   ├── module1.py
 └── package2
     ├── __init__.py
     └── module2.py
```

> Notice that I've also added an empty **`__init__.py`** into the **proj-dir** itself which makes it a package too.

Now, if you want to import any python object from **module2** of **package2** into **module1** of **package1**, then the **import** statement in the file **module1.py** would be

```
from proj-dir.package2.module2 import object2
# if you were to import the entire module2 then,
from proj-dir.package2 import module2
```

Comment: I'm puzzled as to this being an accepted answer. The question is clearly about programatic import not fixed structure regular import statements.

Adding the __init__.py at the top levels ties the two directories together in a package and it's no longer about importing using import lib from a separate structure outside the package

Comment: Agree with Henrik, this doesn't answer the question about programmatically loading modules. I'm also seeking the truth about how relative paths work. In my case it's a streamlit app calling a module that dynamically loads a package.